# MIT-Scheme SICP Exercise_1.11 -- object #t is not applicable

Tags: syntax, scheme

This is my first post on StackOverflow.  I have been working on Exercise 1.11 from SICP and feel I have a viable solution.  In transferring from paper to Emacs I seem to have some syntax error that I am unaware of.  I tried my best to double and triple check the parenthesis and solve it but the terminal is still giving me an 'object #t is not applicable' message.  Could someone please point me in the right direction of how to fix the code so I can test its output properly?"

Exercise 1.11: A function f

is defined by the rule that:

f(n)=n
if n<3

, and

f(n)=f(n−1)+2f(n−2)+3f(n−3)
if n>=3

Write a procedure that computes f by means of a recursive process.
Write a procedure that computes f by means of an iterative process.

```
(define (f-recur n)
  (if ((< n 3) n)
      (+ (f(- n 1))
     (* 2 (f(n-2)))
     (* 3 (f(n-3)))))

(define (f-iter n)
  (define (counter n)
    (if (<= n 3) 0)
    (- n 3))
  (define (d n) (+ n (* 2 n) (* 3 n)))
  (define (c n) (+ d (* 2 n) (* 3 n)))
  (define (b n) (+ c (* 2 d) (* 3 n)))
  (define (a n) (+ b (* 2 c) (* 3 d)))
  (define (f a b c d counter)
    (if ((> (+ counter 3) n) a)
      (f  (+ b (* 2 c) (* 3 d)) a b c (+ counter 1)))))
  
  (cond ((= counter 0) d)
    ((= counter 1) c)
    ((= counter 2) b)
    ((= counter 3) a)
    (else (f a b c d counter))))
```

Comment: `counter` is the function defined with `(define (counter n) ...)`. What are you expecting `(= counter 0)` to do? You're not calling the function, you're just comparing the function itself with `0`

Comment: `premature EOF` means your parentheses aren't balanced.

Comment: You have a similar problem here: `(+ d (* 2 n) (* 3 n))` `d` is the name of a function. You're not calling the function, you're trying to add the function to numbers.

Comment: In Emacs you can use `M-x find-unbalanced-parentheses`

Comment: Maybe `(+ d (* 2 n) (* 3 n))` should be `(+ (d n) (* 2 n) (* 3 n))`

Comment: I started my programming with Java and the syntax and style have been an adjustment with Scheme.  I will look over the comments some more and determine what I have done incorrectly and correct it.

Comment: I am really trying to understand the key shortcuts like the one you mentioned.  How is it performed, exactly?

Comment: What key shortcuts? M-x means Meta-x in Emacs, you should be familiar with that. It's used to execute lots of named commands.

Comment: I will be doing my research on it then.  Found plenty to look at for it.  I couldn't find the keywords that would let me get the information I needed.  I've adjusted the code quite a bit per your instruction.  How should I post it when I am finished?  I'm pretty sure I shouldn't edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure SICP is looking for a solution in the manner of this iterative fibonnacci:

```
(define (fib n)
  (define (helper n a b)
    (if (zero? n)
        a
        (helper (- n 1) b (+ a b))))
  (helper n 0 1))
```

Fibonacci is `f(n)=f(n−1)+f(n−2)` so I guess `f(n)=f(n−1)+2f(n−2)+3f(n−3)` can be made exactly the same way with one extra variable. Your iterative solution looks more like Fortran than Scheme. Try avoiding `set!`.

Comment: This is tail-recursive, not iterative.

Comment: @Barmar The question said "iterative process" as in not growing the stack. It didn't say "iterative procedure" that would be impossible in Scheme. All looping constructs in Scheme is by recursion. eg the `do` loop is syntax sugar for a `letrec` recursion.

Comment: While that's technically true, I interpret instructions like that to be talking about explicit recursion vs iteration -- if something is hidden in an abstraction it doesn't count. If they wanted tail recursion, wouldn't they just say so?

Comment: @Barmar In [1.2.1 in SICP and you'll see the example of an iterative process written recursively](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1). Imagine making a tree iteration with a while loop and a backtracking user stack, eg. in C. It is an iterative function, but it it is still a recursive process because the user stack grows the same way a system stack would do in a recursive function solution. As long as the algorithm is the same the process is the same. iterative or recursive process does not imply iterative or recursive function.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you said re C program, in the last comment. by that measure all CPS re-writes are not iterative processes either. but they usually are considered so. I do agree about your answer showing the iterative Fibonacci, of course.

Comment: @WillNess CPS-rewrites turns every call into tail calls. They do not change the nature of the algorithm so a recursive process stays a recursive process since it will do the job with heap allocation and nested closures.

Comment: those terms are really vague. better to say "constant stack" (actual, real, not "simulated") usage, or "constant memory overall" usage (*that* would include the "simulated stack on the heap"), to be precise and easily understood. also, whether the space used (stack or not) is exponential, linear, or logarithmic, is what really matters.

Comment: also, (this is meta), you've spent time understanding and answering the question, but it is really hard to follow in its current badly formatted state. perhaps if you'd edited the question into shape your answer could be better understood and appreciated.